# Calculating entropy change in water and copper?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

> A student submerges one tip of a copper bar into a reservoir
>   of boiling water at 100 ° C and the other tip in a mixture of water
>   and ice at 0 ° C. Both bars are isolated. After the bar reached a
>   steady state, 0.16 kg of ice had melted over a certain period of time,
>   ∆t. The water has a specific heat capacity of 4186 J / kg · K and
>   enthalpy of fusion of 3.34 × 105 J / kg.
>   -What is the entropy change of the boiling water?
>   -What is the entropy change of the water and ice mixture?
>   -What is the entropy change of the copper bar?

To calculate the entropy change, I was using

ΔS = mass * specific heat * ln [T final/ T object] ( this is the formula the professor taught us)

(in this case, i think Tfinal is the bar's temperature and Tobject is the temperature of cold or hot water)

but I am having difficulties in finding a way to calculate it without knowing the liquid's mass and the bar's temperature.

Comment: In my judgment, it is a shame that this thread was closed.  There are important underlying physical concepts that could have been brought to light in answering this question that, as a result, have been denied to members.